# How to create an input page for a parent model whose child has multiple foreign keys in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform, formset, inline-formset

I'm trying to design a single input page using Django that will allow inputting everything about a Customer in one place. My Customers can have multiple Locations. Each Location has a foreign key to not only its Customer, but also to a Contact and an Account Manager (Location has 3 foreign keys in all). Customer, Location, Contact, and Account Manager are all models; all of them have several text and boolean fields in addition to the foreign keys on Location that I already mentioned.

Ideally, the input page will allow a user to input a single Customer while also creating multiple new Locations, and creating a new Contact and Account Manager for each one -- or optionally selecting an existing Contact or Account Manager.

What is the best way to plan the design of this input page? Should I be looking at ModelForms and InlineFormsets? Or should I be creating a new Django Form from scratch? Or a Formset based on several Django Forms?

I haven't provided any code because I'm less interested in exact implementation than in how to approach this problem, but I can provide details if necessary; let me know. Higher-level advice is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**What I would do:**

Since you're dealing with models, a ModelForm would be the easiest because it automatically checks the arguments supplied in your models, like `max_length`, etc.

And since you have so many ForeignKeys, and because I don't know how many fields each model has *(though it sounds like you have A LOT)*... To simplify the code, if I were you I would make a view for just the Customer to be created. Why? Because that's your parent model, and the other's can't exist without it.

After that I'd make a separate view to allow that new Customer to add a new Location one at a time, and set the proper Contact and AccountManager along with it, because like you said, they could add any number of them. If you did it all at once, displaying X number of extra forms on the same page for them to fill out more Location, Contact, and AccountManager forms is more likely to have more errors from the user. Keeping things separate could help reduce that. Since you haven't shown any code I can't really say much more than this, because I don't know which of those other model fields are required or not, or even how many you have, but it sounds like a lot of fields.

**More comments:**

The downside of 2 separate views, one for the parent, and another for the children, is you have more queries, which takes longer to find each object, though neglibile, but it's important to design around optimizing towards as few requests as possible.

The upside is clarity for the user, so they know 1 thing needs to be done at a time, and it's also easier for you to write the code because you won't have to take X number of the other potential models. Let's say you had a Customer with 10 each of the other models, and you wanted it all collected in one view... Writing a function for that would be a lot harder.

**It would be helpful if you put some of your own code here,** because it sounds to me like you want to make like a receipt with their address, phone, and location, and if I'm right about that, you could easily put some of the fields from Contact and Location inside the Customer model. Or maybe even set some of those fields in the Customer model as some default location and contact fields, and then if the user wants more, give them the view to let them make an extra Location, Contact, and AccountManager.